# How can I get NSwag to recognise the "application/json" return type on a POST route?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nswag

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string filename = null, bool transmit = true)
```

NSwag isn't recognising the `Produces("application/json")` attribute. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by `recognising the Produces("application/json")`? By default, its 
Response content type is `application/json`. What is your current result and your expected result? Share us a screen shot about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]